# jquery mobile datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery mobile datepicker. As with the standard jquery datepicker I am trying to set mindate.

However the calendar load but the min date does not set. Only when I click on the calendar does the dates block out.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
        $('#calendar').live('pagecreate',function(event){


            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
               minDate: 0,
             });
        });
```

Comment: what version of jqm are you using? the datepicker hasn't been in there since alpha.

Comment: I am using final release 1.0 of jqm. The mindate works fine if I put it on the calendar page and load it on it's own. But when I call the calendar page through ajax form the main page it does not set http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the jqm experimental calendar is supported at this point, but give the [Mobiscroll Calendar](http://mobiscroll.com/component/calendar) a try.

Setting the min date is easy

```
$("#calendar").mobiscroll().calendar({
    minDate: new Date(2013, 2, 23)
});
```